# Removing white space in textbox using JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a text box in my JSP-page which allow user to enter the name also in which I have given the max limit in 30 character.

But when user enters the empty white space it count the and does not allow character to enter once it reaches the max limit.

I want that when the white spaces is enter  user should  able to enter the character. It should not count white spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var txt = $("#myTextbox");
  var func = function() {
    txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
  }
  txt.keyup(func).blur(func);
});
```

You have to additionally handle the `blur` event because user could use context menu to paste.

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/aEHfG/)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all space with empty string and count characters.try this code :

```
function get(str){str = str.replace(/\./g,' ');return str.length;}
```

Comment: How sir any sample code.  My function is like this                   var title=$("#auto").val().trim();

Answer (score 0):

Or again:

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    var t = $(this).val();
    console.log(t.replace(/\s/g, '').length);
    if(t.replace(/\s/g, '').length >= 10) alert('max');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the

```
$('input').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {             // if the user presses 'space',
        $(this).val(function(i, val) {
            return val.replace('  ', ' '); // find and replace 'double spaces' and replace it with one 'space
        });
    }
});​
```

check my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TSkj3/16/)

this code allows for the max of ONE space next to each other incase the user wants to put a last name. just and option. if you dont want this then use the code from the other answers.